# Adding Security Headers (HSTS) for API with AWS managed (internal) CloudFront (with zone id Z2FDTNDATAQYW2)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, api-gateway, response-headers, hsts

We have some API Gateway domains (created with Terraform) that are defined as 'edge-optimized', therefore API Gateway internally creates and manages a CloudFront distribution to route requests on the given hostnames. It seems it doesn't come with HSTS Policy enabled (checked via hardenize), so I'd like to modify Security Headers configuration within aws_cloudfront_response_headers_policy (e.g. strict_transport_security and xss_protection parameters) with Terraform, but unable to find a way.

Do you have any solution for this? Is it even possible?

I tried to search on the internet, but couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
resource "aws_cloudfront_response_headers_policy" "headers_policy" {
  name = "security-headers-policy"
 strict_transport_security {
      override = true
      access_control_max_age_sec = 63072000
      include_subdomains = true
      preload = true
    }

    xss_protection {
      override = true
      mode_block = true
      protection = true
    }
}
```

and then you attach this policy to default cache behaviour

```
default_cache_behavior {
    allowed_methods = ["GET", "HEAD"]
    cached_methods = ["GET", "HEAD"]
    compress = true
    viewer_protocol_policy = "redirect-to-https"
    response_headers_policy_id = aws_cloudfront_response_headers_policy.headers_policy.id
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer but we have our own CloudFront distribution as well and we already have and use these configurations, but we needed to implement this to AWS managed CloudFront as well, can it be done? Or in other words, can aws_cloudfront_distribution be used for AWS managed CloudFront, if yes how?

Comment: What do you mean by AWS-managed CloudFront? AWS provides a way to configure CloudFront distribution and you do it via console or IaC.

Comment: In an edge-optimized configuration, API Gateway internally creates and manages a CloudFront distribution to route requests on the given hostname.
Source: https://www.pulumi.com/registry/packages/aws/api-docs/apigateway/domainname/